# Remove argument to buildSessionFactory()

Tags: java

While passing `ServiceRegistry` obj into `buildSessionFactory()` I am getting the following error:

> Remove argument to buildSessionFactory()

I am using hibernate 5.4.2

```
public class SessionFact {

static SessionFactory sf;
private static ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;
public static SessionFactory getSessionFact() {
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.configure("/Resources/hibernate.cfg.xml");
    serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(config.getProperties()).build();
    sf = config.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
    System.out.println(org.hibernate.Version.getVersionString());
    return sf;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From hibernate 5.2 or above you could use StandardServiceRegistry in the below way:

```
private static StandardServiceRegistry registry;
  private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

  public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    if (sessionFactory == null) {
      try {
        // Creating a registry
        registry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").build();

        // Create the MetadataSources
        MetadataSources sources = new MetadataSources(registry);

        // Create the Metadata
        Metadata metadata = sources.getMetadataBuilder().build();

        // Create SessionFactory
        sessionFactory = metadata.getSessionFactoryBuilder().build();
        //or sessionFactory = sources.buildSessionFactory();


      } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        if (registry != null) {
          StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.destroy(registry);
        }
      }
    }
    return sessionFactory;
  }

  //To shut down
 public static void shutdown() {
    if (registry != null) {
      StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.destroy(registry);
    }
  }
```

More details: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#bootstrap-native-SessionFactory

Comment: @Raj.thakur Glad to help you. Could you please mark the answer as useful. Thank you.